# Let $f(x) = x^n$. Show that $f^{(n)} = n!$ and $f^{(m)} (x) = 0$ for all $m > n$.

Tags: derivatives, induction, factorial

I'm supposed to use mathematical induction to solve this

1. Show that $P(1)$ is true
2. Assume $P(K)$ is true
3. Show that $P(K+1)$ is true

How do I approach this problem?

Comment: If $f(x)=x^{n+1}$ then $f'(x)=(n+1)x^n$. Note that $f^{(n+1)}(x)=f' ^{(n)}(x)$.

Comment: Wow, this question needs some serious editing!

Answer (score 5):

You approach the problem by following the steps. Keep in mind that $P(n)$ is the statement

> $f^{(n)} = n!$ and $f^{(m)}(x)=0$ for $m>n$.

- Now, if this is $P(n)$, what is $P(1)$?
- How would you prove that $P(1)$ is true?

Once that is done, try to write down $P(k)$ (which is what you **assume** to be true) and $P(k+1)$ (which is what you want to prove). Write them both down and try to see what the connection between them is. The statements will be very similar.

Comment: First and second steps seem pretty clear. I got $f^{(k+1)}(x) = k(k-1)x^{k-2}$ in the third step; which looks similar to the proof @Jan showed below. Is this right?

Comment: The equation $f^{(k+1)}(x) = k(k-1)x^{k-2}$ makes no sense without telling me what you are proving.

Comment: I'm trying to prove $f^{(n)} = n!$ and $f^{(m)}(x) = 0$ when $m > n$. I kinda see it but i don't have a clue how to show it

Answer (score 1):

Notice, $n\in\mathbb{Z^+}$:

$$\frac{\text{d}^n}{\text{d}x^n}\left(x^a\right)=\begin{cases}a!\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\text{when}\space n=a\\
0\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\text{when}\space n>a\\
\frac{a!}{(a-n)!}\cdot x^{a-n}\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\text{when}\space n<a
\end{cases}$$

Because (example):

$$\frac{\text{d}^3}{\text{d}x^3}\left(x^2\right)=\frac{\text{d}^2}{\text{d}x^2}\left(2x^1\right)=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(2x^0\right)=0$$
$$\frac{\text{d}^3}{\text{d}x^3}\left(x^3\right)=\frac{\text{d}^2}{\text{d}x^2}\left(3x^2\right)=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(6x^1\right)=6x^0=6=3!$$

And to proof those, use this:

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(x^a\right)=ax^{a-1}$$
$$\frac{\text{d}^2}{\text{d}x^2}\left(x^a\right)=a(a-1)x^{a-2}$$
$$\frac{\text{d}^3}{\text{d}x^3}\left(x^a\right)=a(a-1)(a-2)x^{a-3}$$
$$\frac{\text{d}^4}{\text{d}x^4}\left(x^a\right)=a(a-1)(a-2)(a-3)x^{a-4}$$
$$\frac{\text{d}^5}{\text{d}x^5}\left(x^a\right)=a(a-1)(a-2)(a-3)(a-4)x^{a-5}$$